# How to find if a number contains any digit from another number

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to check if any digit of a  number say 23 is present in another number say 25.

If present my function should return as false for that check
e.g: 
25 contains the digit 2 from the number 23 , hence return false

Comment: Stackoverflow is for helping you to get your code working rather than writing it for you. There is a much higher chance this question won't just be closed if you make an attempt yourself and then ask why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function like this one:

```
def shared_digits(a, b):
    return not any(map(lambda x: x in str(a), str(b)))
```

This will check if any of the digits in number `b` is on `a`, and return false is there is.

Comment: This isn't very efficient.

Comment: I agree, your answer is better.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the integer to a string, then the elements of the string to a [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), then compare, using [**`set.isdisjoint`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint):

```
>>> a = 25
>>> b = 23

>>> set(str(a)).isdisjoint(str(b))
False
```

Note, you don't need to convert both `a` and `b` into sets. `isdisjoint` takes any sequence as it will go through in a linear fashion until it finds a matching character. To build a set from `b` first would be inefficient.

Comment: And you broke it with a really great answer. Congratulations.

Comment: Aw, shucks @dawg, you made me blush.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are asking 'Given two numbers, I want to know if any of the digits of the first number are in the second number' - which is basically a 'check if substring' problem - or something else.

In case I guessed correctly, this might help you:

```
if set(str(number1)).intersection(set(str(number2))):
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all`:

```
>>> all(d in str(25) for d in str(21))
False
>>> all(d in str(2231) for d in str(31))
True
```